# How is the right way of usage Twisted Services

Tags: python, service, twisted

I'm start to learning twisted python

but when I try to do some experiments with official examples i can't get  successful result with twisted services

let's look at this example:

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/_downloads/finger12.tac

```
class FingerProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):

    def lineReceived(self, user):

        print '+++++++++ line getter' # the execution of this app never print this line


class FingerSetterProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print '+++++++++ line setter' # the execution of this app never print this line
        self.lines.append(line)
```

result from twistd:

```
shell$ twistd -noy pizza1.tac 

2014-12-12 16:04:57+0200 [-] Log opened.

2014-12-12 16:04:57+0200 [-] twistd 13.2.0 (/usr/bin/python 2.7.6) starting up.

2014-12-12 16:04:57+0200 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.

2014-12-12 16:04:57+0200 [-] FingerFactory starting on 9000

2014-12-12 16:04:57+0200 [-] Starting factory <__builtin__.FingerFactory instance at 
0x7f3b66dfd998>

2014-12-12 16:04:57+0200 [-] FingerSetterFactory starting on 9001

2014-12-12 16:04:57+0200 [-] Starting factory <__builtin__.FingerSetterFactory instance at 0x7f3b66dfdbd8>

2014-12-12 16:04:57+0200 [-] set uid/gid 1000/1000
```

result from pip freeze:

```
Twisted==14.0.2

argparse==1.2.1

wsgiref==0.1.2

zope.interface==4.1.1
```

python version:

> Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)

if somebody knows why `lineReceived` is not running will be happy to help

my test code:

```
from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, defer
from twisted.protocols import basic


class FingerProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):

    def connectionMade(self):
        print '+++++++++ getter is coming'

    def lineReceived(self, user):

        print '+++++++++ line getter'

        d = self.factory.getUser(user)

        def onError(err):

            return '+++++++++ Internal error in server'

        d.addErrback(onError)

        def writeResponse(message):

            print '+++++++++ getter write'
            self.transport.write(message + '\r\n')
            self.transport.loseConnection()

        d.addCallback(writeResponse)


class FingerFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):

    protocol = FingerProtocol

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print '+++++++++ init factory'
        self.users = kwargs

    def getUser(self, user):
        print '+++++++++ get user'
        return defer.succeed(self.users.get(user, "No such user"))

class FingerSetterProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):

    def connectionMade(self):
        print '+++++++++ setter is coming'
        self.lines = []

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print '+++++++++ line setter'
        self.lines.append(line)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print '+++++++++ connection lost'
        user = self.lines[0]
        status = self.lines[1]
        self.factory.setUser(user, status)


class FingerSetterFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):

    protocol = FingerSetterProtocol

    def __init__(self, fingerFactory):
        print '+++++++++ init setter factory'
        self.fingerFactory = fingerFactory

    def setUser(self, user, status):
        print '+++++++++ set user'
        self.fingerFactory.users[user] = status

ff = FingerFactory(targy='Happy and well')
fsf = FingerSetterFactory(ff)

application = service.Application('finger', uid=1000, gid=1000)
serviceCollection = service.IServiceCollection(application)
internet.TCPServer(9000,ff).setServiceParent(serviceCollection)
internet.TCPServer(9001,fsf).setServiceParent(serviceCollection)
```

Comment: Did you try to connect to the finger server?  If so, what did you use to do so?

Comment: the issue was solved. in beginning I did my tests with nc and looks nc don't send '\r\n' of the end of line, so when I testing with telnet everything works fine